# XQuery content between two singleton tags

Tags: xml, xquery

do you know to do XQuery query for selection of content between two singleton tags, e.g.

```
<pb n="1"/>
   this is <foo>page</foo> number one
<pb n="2"/>
   this is <bar>page</bar> number two
<pb n="3"/>
   this is <x>page</x> number three
```

and I want for example content of second page, so between `<pb n="2"/>` and next `<pb/>`. Output should be then:

```
   this is <bar>page</bar> number two
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `following-sibling` together with the `<<` operator, like this:

```
let $xml := <xml>
<pb n="1"/> 
   this is <foo>page</foo> number one 
<pb n="2"/> 
   this is <bar>page</bar> number two 
<pb n="3"/> 
   this is <x>page</x> number three 
</xml>
return
  $xml/pb[2]/following-sibling::node()[. << $xml/pb[3]]
```

HTH!

Comment: To find the next `<pb/>`, you can also use `$xml/pb[@n=2]/following-sibling::pb[1]` which returns the first node which is a page break tag.

Answer (score 1):

See David Sewell's [milestone-chunk()](http://wiki.tei-c.org/index.php/Milestone-chunk.xquery) function on the TEI wiki.  Note that this article also points to an eXist-db extension function, [util:get-fragment-between()](http://demo.exist-db.org/exist/functions/util/get-fragment-between).

Answer (score 0):

**Just this query, which happens to be a pure XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
/*/node()[not(self::pb) and preceding-sibling::pb[1]/@n eq '2']
```

**When executed on this XML document** (the provided XML fragment wrapped into a single top element):

```
<t>
    <pb n="1"/>
       this is <foo>page</foo> number one
    <pb n="2"/>
       this is <bar>page</bar> number two
    <pb n="3"/>
       this is <x>page</x> number three
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
   this is <bar>page</bar> number two
```